# Implicit Broadcast Receiver on Android Oreo and higher

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

My Broadcast receiver is not working when my application has been cleared from recently used apps. I am able to receive broadcasts and see the toast when the app is active. I am aware of the [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) that have been imposed from Oreo. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` is one of the exceptions that can register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts. But I am not able to see the toast after application has been cleared from recently used apps tab. Is anyone facing similar problems? Here is my code that I used.

**Permission Used** - AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

**Receiver** - AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<receiver android:name=".receiver.IncomingCallReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Receiever Class** - IncomingCallReceiver.java

```java
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "IncomingCallReceiever";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
            .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "application has been cleared" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry if the wording wasn't clear. As in when you close applications using this [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez0h9.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps your device was made by a manufacturer that treats those gestures as equivalent to "Force Stop" in the Settings screen for your app. There are some devices like that, though fortunately not many (yet). You might also consider using something other than `Toast`, such as `Log` statements, in case the problem is not the receipt of the broadcast but your ability to display the `Toast`.

Comment: I'm using an emulator (Pixel 2 and Pixel 3) to debug the app. Would that cause any problem? And I've tried using `Log` statements just didn't include it for the example above.

Comment: "Would that cause any problem?" -- I don't know much about how the emulator deals with this broadcast in general. If this is the official Android SDK emulator, though, I would not expect "Force Stop"-style behavior for swiping the app off the overview screen.